# What are the benefits of migrating to RAD version 8 for Commerce?

Tags: websphere-commerce

I can tell that you can, if you are running the newest FEP, as there is an official migration guide. There is also a nice list of new features on the RAD site. What I can't find is a list of features that are relevant for Commerce.

As far as I can tell, all I get is a slightly newer (but still outdated) Eclipse platform. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: Not much, unless some blocking bug is fixed. The Eclipse that RAD 8 is based on is pretty much as outdated as the one in RAD 7.5, so no modern plugins or GWT for you!!!!

Comment: What a loaded FUD answer.  It's like saying there is no difference between JDKs.   Anyhow RAD is more than Eclipse and if you didn't want to take the time to understand, then it is what it is.

Comment: In terms of Commerce it brings nothing to our project, and as far as I can tell little to others. I stand by that assessment. No need to resort to name calling really - tut tut!